# Can not call defined funtions from .bashrc

Tags: command-line, bashrc, zsh

I have a function in `.bashrc` like this:

```
function gs () {
  cmm="$1"
  if test -z "$cmm"
  then
    cmm="This is Manh Cuong's commit ."
  fi
  
  git add . && git commit -m "$cmm" && git push
}
```

It worked well with `gs` and `gs "new commit"` commands in terminal. But I have just installed **zsh**, **oh-my-zsh** on my Ubuntu 20.04 Asus laptop. Then I call `gs` or `gs "new commit"`, it does not work anymore. I do not know how to fix it. Could anybody help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: `cmm=${1:-"This is Manh ..."}`, you don't really need that if-statement. `${parameter:-word}` expands to `word` if `$parameter` is "empty".

Comment: Oh I have just known that, I am going to update my .zshrc with this option

Comment: @bac0n is that for zsh only, or does it also work for bash?

Comment: bash, dash, ksh, zsh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're running `zsh` shell then you have to put this in `~/.zshrc` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

Once you've added it there, you can either open a new terminal or run
`source ~/.zshrc` to use it.